# Yii2 Using Multiple Checkbox Fields

Tags: checkbox, yii, yii2

I have a Yii2 app in which I want to use multiple checkbox as array. The checkbox is part of my Model, but it's not a DB column. It also has a custom value.

I loop through a list of days, set a custom value for the checkboxes and print the checkboxes to my view like this:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'dayIds[]')->checkbox(
            ['value' => $day->id.'_'.$person->id])->label(false);
```

On my Model side I have this:

```
public $dayIds;

foreach ($this->dayIds as $dayId) {
     //do something
}
```

I have tried many different scenarios but always end up with error on my Model that $this->dayIds is null.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Do you have a rule setup for $dayIds?

Comment: Hi Graig, yes, when I add it to rules then I get the values. This is great for me at least, but how do you then get a value which you don't want in the rules, or maybe tell it to skip rules? I mean in all other languages I have worked with, when I put something in the form tags and post the form, I am able to get any and all values.

Comment: Instead of using load(), you can use setAttributes() with the flag to allow non-safe values to be set and then you wouldn’t need the rule.  But I don’t recommend it.  The rules are there for a reason.  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#setAttributes()-detail

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at both options.

Answer (score 0):

The array variable `dayIds[]` and scalar variable `$dayIds` are two different variables. You can define `dayIds1`, `dayIds2`, etc. or alternatively `dayIds[1]`, `dayIds[2]`, etc.

Basically, I don't see `$this->dayIds` being assigned anything - so it will always be null.